# Images not shown when using IIS but shown in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

I'm not able to get my images when I run it in my IIS but are coming up if I use IIS Express.

I found couple solutions on the net regarding this:

1. The omission of Static File Handler in my IIS and checking the
         Stactic Content under -  Turn Windows Features On or Off - Common HTTP
         Features.
2. This stack post ([After switching Visual Studio to use local IIS server, image and style files not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027895/after-switching-visual-studio-to-use-local-iis-server-image-and-style-files-not))

Many got their problems solved with the first solution. But, I already have ,`Static Content`which is checked. The second one was also not helpful.

Could anyone help me understand what I might be missing?

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Not able to get my images" please clarify what you mean. What type of error such as a runtime error, file not found, access denied, server 500? Your AppPool Identity is set to NetworkService? It has appropriate permissions?

Comment: Press F12 in your browser. The error should be there.

Comment: @dan I've already checked it. The image path is not getting resolved. Like: If my Virtual Directory in IIS Express is `localhost:8080/xyz`. The images are loaded. But, If I try to run it in IIS. with the some path like: `localhost\xyz`. They are not resolving the path.
Edit: my Image path would `\Images\Icons\xyz.png`

Comment: @lloyd: It is a `failed to load resource. 404 error`. Sorry to be naive. But, what effect does my IIS AppPool Identity has on my image path? 
PS: I'm running it under Custom Account.

Comment: [Identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). So the custom account has access to these files (ACL)? And you've tried switching it to ApplicationPoolIdentity and running ICACLS?

Comment: @lloyd: Yeah. I switched to AppPoolIdentity and the AppPool stopped whenever I tried to run the application. Checked EventViewer. This was the error I saw: `A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration`
Edit: This is the first time I've stumbled across this.Does this mean I don't have sufficient previlages?

Comment: This may be adding to your issues instead of solving them. I'm not sure how to fix it and refer to uncle Google: [modify the hkey](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e4d701f5-a63f-4fee-9b09-89ea9b07e1c3/the-diagnostic-service-host-service-failed-to-start-due-to-the-following-error?forum=w7itprogeneral). Do you need to have a look at the route config for how it resolves where the image is located? If so please add your controller action method, view and route config that are related.

Answer (score 0):

404 suggests that the resource was not found. Verify that your image path is correct. Use Firebug or any HTML debugging tools to find the exact issue.